# Using awk substr on fixed width file

Tags: awk, substr

I have a fixed width file where I would like to split rows by a value defined by the first four characters into files called `file_1985.dat` & `file_1986.dat`. Take this minimal file:

```
$ cat foo.dat
1985tiny dancer
1986largechicken
1985hey  jude
```

I would like to end up with this:

```
$ cat file_1985.dat
1985tiny dancer
1985hey  jude
```

and this:

```
$ cat file_1986.dat
1986largechicken
```

I am pretty sure I need to do something like this:

```sh
awk -F, '{if(???)print > "file_1985.dat";else print > "file_1986.dat"}' foo.dat
```

where `???` involves some use of `substr`. Can anyone advise here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `substr($0, 1, 4)` to get the 4 characters that you want to go in the filename (a substring starting at character `1` of length `4`):

```
awk '{ 
  out = "file_" substr($0, 1, 4) ".dat" # set filename
  if (out != prev) close(prev)          # close previous file
  print >> out                          # write to file
  prev = out                            # remember filename to check on next line
}' foo.dat
```

The filename `out` comes from the result of concatenating the string literals with the result of `substr`. This variable is used to determine the file that `print`'s output ends up in.

`>>` opens a file in "append mode", which means that if you re-open the same file, you don't lose the previous content.

Testing it out:

```
$ awk '{ out = "file_" substr($0, 1, 4) ".dat"; if (out != prev) close(prev); print >> out; prev = out  }' foo.dat
$ cat file_1985.dat 
1985tiny dancer
1985hey  jude
$ cat file_1986.dat 
1986largechicken
```

The use of `close` is a precaution to prevent opening too many files, but if your input isn't too big then you can simplify to just:

```
awk '{ print > ("file_" substr($0, 1, 4) ".dat") }' foo.dat
```

Regarding performance, you could try sorting the input, to avoid opening and closing the same files repeatedly (although sorting would itself take time):

```
sort -s -k1.1,1.4 foo.dat | awk '{ out = "file_" substr($0, 1, 4) ".dat"; if (out != prev) close(prev); print > out; prev = out  }'
```

Here I also changed the `>>` to `>` since awk will only open each file once.

You could also avoid repeating the same string concatenation once per line by caching the results:

```
{
  ss = substr($0, 1, 4)
  if (!(ss in outs)) {
    outs[ss] = "file_" ss ".dat"
  }
  out = outs[ss]
  if (out != prev) close(prev)
  print >> out
  prev = out
}
```

Put it in a script like `script.awk` and run it like `awk -f script.awk foo.dat`.

Comment: Can you explain how this knows 1985 and 1986? Does it just take any unique values within the first four characters?

Comment: This ends up being quite a slow solution for a biggish file (4Gb). I didn't original ask for speed but do you have suggestions on how to speed this up?

Comment: @boshek I added some ideas for how to speed up the script.

Answer (score 0):

```
gawk -v FIELDWIDTHS="4 200" '{ print $2 > "file_" $1 ".dat" }' foo.dat
```

from the man-page:
If  the  FIELDWIDTHS  variable  is  set to a space-separated list of numbers, each field is expected to have fixed width, and gawk splits up the record using the specified widths.  Each field width may
       optionally be preceded by a colon-separated value specifying the number of characters to skip before the field starts.  The value of FS is ignored.  Assigning a new value to FS or  FPAT  overrides  the
       use of FIELDWIDTHS.

Comment: With recent gawk releases you can use `*` as the final string in FIELDWIDTHS to stand for "whatever's left" rather than having to specify a number that you hope is large enough, e.g. `FIELDWIDTHS='4 *'`. See https://lists.gnu.org/archive/html/bug-gawk/2017-05/msg00018.html.

Comment: I was testing this with gawk 4.2.1, but did not notice that on the man-page... 

Answer (score 0):

If you're using GNU awk or you'll have fewer than about 12 output files then:

```
awk '{print > ("file_"substr($0,1,4)".dat")}' foo.dat
```

otherwise to avoid a "too many open files" error:

```
awk '{out="file_"substr($0,1,4)".dat"; print >> out; close(out)}' foo.dat
```